# How to replace a value in a dataset django

Tags: python, django

I have a dataset from a model with 40 fields. Is there a smart way to replace a certain value (like `NULL`)?

I have tried with nested for loops without success.

Comment: For a certain field? For all fields? With what value?

Comment: Corrected spelling.

Comment: for example replace NULL value for all fields in a dataset. now i've resolved with a for loop and multiple IF statement, there is a better way to do this?